# Android okhttp Async progressdialog

Tags: android, asynchronous, progressdialog, okhttp

I want to add progressdialog into okhttp (asynchronous, not AsyncTask)

but i got this error:

> Error: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called
>   Looper.prepare()

How to fix it in a proper way? I want to be sure that is the best way to do this.

```
  client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Log.d("TAG_response", " brak neta lub polaczenia z serwerem ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                 progress = ProgressDialog.show(SignUp.this, "dialog title",
                    "dialog message", true);
            try {
                Log.d("TAGx", response.body().string());
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
                    for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                        //System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                        Log.d("TAG2", responseHeaders.name(i));
                        Log.d("TAG3", responseHeaders.value(i));

                    }
                    Log.d("TAG", response.body().string());
                    progress.dismiss();
                    main_activity();
                }
                else{
                    progress.dismiss();

                    alertUserAboutError();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                Log.d("TAG", "error");
            }

        }

    });
```

Comment: You should move code for showing dialog before enqueuing the request and dismiss in onFailure and onResponse.

Answer (score 3):

OkHttp runs the onResponse method on the same background thread which it does the http call on.  Because you're doing an async call this means it will not be the Android main thread.

To run code on the main thread from onResponse you can use a Handler and Runnable:

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

    Handler handler = new Handler(SignUp.this.getMainLooper());

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                // whatever you want to do on the main thread
            }
        });
    }
```